# why does directly passing svg url is not working for mat-icon in Angular?

Tags: angular, mat-icon

This code works fine:

```
<mat-icon class="cost-list-icon"></mat-icon>
```

```
.cost-list-icon {
    content: url('/assets/icons/mdi_list-box-outline.svg');
}
```

But when I try to use it directly in html file it does not work. It is not working like this:

```
<mat-icon class="content: url('/assets/icons/mdi_list-box-outline.svg')"></mat-icon>
```

I would like to know how can I make it work directly in html file? If someone knows then please let me know. Thanks in advance

Comment: Because it's a style, not a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of class, you have to use style. It can work as follows:

```
<mat-icon style="content: url('/assets/icons/mdi_list-box-outline.svg')"></mat-icon>
```